# How to open a new window from already opened window in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have problem with dynamically opening new window from already opened window. There are several links on the page, and since I have script to do before change page is fired and cannot simply add `target="_blank"`, I do like this:

```
<a href="somelink" class="someclass">Blah Blah</a>
```

and in javascript

```
$(document).on("click",".someclass",function(event){
    let href = this.href;
    event.preventDefault();
    /*
        ... 
        here I do some stuff
        ...
    */
    window.open(href,null);
});
```

and this IS opening a new window (new tab). On that newly opened window there are also links with `.someclass` class but when clicking on that link all is done except it is not opening in a new window, instead it is opening in the same window.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out... problem was "null" parameter for window. I just put

`window.open(href, Math.random()+"");`

and it is working.